# Show that $X - Y$ is not uniformly distributed on (a,b) for some a<b

Tags: probability-theory

Let X and Y be independent and identically distributed. 
Show that $X - Y$ is not uniformly distributed on (a,b) for some  $a<b$.

Let $Z = X - Y$. I know that in order for $Z$ to be uniformly distributed in some interval $(a,b)$ it will be when $a = -b$. And as  X and Y are identically distributed, then they will have the same characteristic function.

I don't really know how to keep going using characteristic functions. I'd appreciate any hint! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic function of uniform distribution on $(-a,a)$ is $\frac  1 {2a}\int_{-a}^{a} e^{itx} dx=\frac {\sin (at)} {at}$. Note that this function takes both positive and negative values. However $Ee^{it(X-Y)}=|Ee^{itX}|^{2} \geq 0$. Hence $X-Y$ cannot be uniformly distributed . (I have used your observation the interval on which we have uniform distribution has to be symmetric).

Comment: Hi @Kabo, thanks for your help. Just to check if I got it clear. We have that $\mathrm{\varphi}_{X-Y}(t) = \mathrm{\varphi}_{X}(t)\mathrm{\varphi}_{-Y}(t) = \mathrm{\varphi}_{X}(t)\overline{\mathrm{\varphi}_{Y}(t)} = \mathrm{\varphi}_{X}(t)\overline{\mathrm{\varphi}_{X}(t)} = |\mathrm{\varphi}_{X}(t)|^2$ which has to be greater or equal than zero. Then, I could find a value of $a$ for which $ 0< a < b$ (while $t$ can take any value) for which the characteristic function will be negative and as it has to be strictly positive X-Y can not then be uniformly distributed on $(a,b)$.

Comment: @Sophie_s Yes, you got it clear.